# Android: stretch text so that the letters fill the device screen

Tags: android, textview, stretch

I'm trying to stretch text so that a given string fills the entire screen. I know how to make the TextView object fill the screen, but can't get the actual letters to do the same. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is some static text you could just strech it manually

```
yourTextView.setTextScaleX((float) 1.6 );  // set to what ever fits
```

you could scale that and check if the words break into two lines in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Webview. Format the text using this (html style):

```
style="text-align:justify"
```

Comment: Doesn't a WebView mean that I would also have to change permissions, etc? Is there a similar style for TextViews?

Comment: I've got bad news and bad news. You do have to use INTERNET permission and, as far as I know, there is now way to justify text in the native TextView.